# How to copy paste in a determinate cell, changing the variable every week (not in the code)

Tags: excel, vba

I receive a weekly table and I've to update various columns in the whole document.

Every week has a target number from 1 to 52.

I tried to make the VBA copy paste in the next free column, but I realized that It can lead you to an error if you don't update it in the proper way.

So I was thinking, do you know a vba code that allows me to decide in the Excel sheet, where the Macro has to copy?
Like I choose the right weekly number in the excel sheet and then run the macro to make it copy in the rightful column in every designated sheet.

This I the code so far that copies in the next available column:

```
Sub copy()
'Meeting

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Weekly")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Meeting 2020")

copySheet.Range("B6:B14").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, 15).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas


Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'proposal

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Weekly")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Proposal 2020")

copySheet.Range("G6:G14").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, 15).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Pipe

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Weekly")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("PIPE 2020")

copySheet.Range("K6:K14").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, 15).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas


Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'date
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set copySheet = Worksheets("Weekly")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets(" date 2020")

copySheet.Range("J6:J13").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, 15).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas


Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59946042/edit) and post the code you've tried and a picture of the data lay out

Comment: Reading [ask] and [mcve] might help you to improve yoour question. Screenshots and example input/output data usually helps a lot to understand questions and locate issues. Consider providing some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few steps are needed to create this.
First: declare a variable that stores the weeknumber ([VBA Convert date to week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973967/vba-convert-date-to-week-number))

Second: use the find function or a loop function to find this number in a range.

Third: extract the column number from that position.

Fourth: use a loop to cycle through all the sheets and paste the information at that column.

This is not a straightforward copy/paste solution, but the steps are concrete.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, in the end I solved with this with an old macro created by my colleague----------------Sub copymytable()

Dim x As Integer

Dim i As String
i = Sheets("Weekly").Range("O1").Value

Sheets("Weekly").Select

Range("G6:G13").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sheet 2020").Select
    Sheets("Sheet 2020").Range(i & 13).Select
    
    
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub