# vba - get weeknumber

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get the current week number.
I tried this:

```
MsgBox (Format(Now, "ww", vbMonday))
```

The result:

```
3
```

But it has to be `2`
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA Convert date to week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973967/vba-convert-date-to-week-number)

Comment: I tried this: `WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(now, vbMonday)`. But same result (3)

Comment: well it's week 3 in the eastern time zone... what time zone is your computer using? week numbers are really confusing... i'm guessing the first week started on Dec 28

Comment: Then if you mean fiscal weeks, sometimes there are 53 of those in a year, but not always

Comment: Timezone is MEZ.

Comment: Europe/Berlin Central European Time (CET)

Comment: did you see every answer in the link that @braX gave in the 1st comment?

Comment: There exist different systems around the world how week numbers are calculated. Make sure you get the right one. If [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is your goal check out the [WorksheetFunction.IsoWeekNum method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.isoweeknum)

Answer (score 2):

```
msgbox format(now(),"ww",vbMonday,vbFirstFourDays)
```

provides the ISO weeknumber, which is what it seems you want.

or:

```
msgbox worksheetfunction.IsoWeekNum(date)
```

Note that there is a bug in the VBA `Format` (and `DatePart`) functions in that they can return the wrong weeknumber for the last Monday of some years when determining the ISO WeekNumber

So if you are going to use the Format function, you need to check for that bug.

`Worksheetfunction.IsoWeekNum` does not have that bug.

To workaround the bug, [Microsoft suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/functions-return-wrong-week-number) checking the weeknumber of the week after any date where the weeknumber calculates to 53.

```
Function WOY (MyDate As Date) As Integer   ' Week Of Year
  WOY = Format(MyDate, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
  If WOY > 52 Then
    If Format(MyDate + 7, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = 2 Then WOY = 1
  End If
End Function
```