# How can I choose a cell according to the current week I'm working on?

Tags: excel, vba

Every Monday I need to copy all from column BW (as it's week 44) to Back (column G) but my column BW changes every week. Also I delete data from Column AY as week 44 will come to end and hide that column. How can I do it?

[image: Please refer to my screenshot of my file]

```
Sub test_1()
'
' test_1 Macro
'

'
Columns("H:AX").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Range("BW2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("G2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that only works for week 44? Where is the input for which week we are looking at? Btw you can hide the columns in 1 line like this: ```Columns("B:B").Hidden = True```.

Comment: Instead of using copy/paste just assign the values `Range("G:G").Value = Range("BW:BW").Value`

Comment: Also - why is "as it's wk 44" relevant to column BW (column 75). (I can't follow the link to your image at work)
You can refer to columns by numbers or ranges as offsets from $A$1 if it's easier and please don't use `Selection` - only recorded macros do that.

Comment: But how can I select BW:BW according to week number, as nxt week when it will be week 45 the range will be BX:BX

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Do you want the macro to figure out what week it is based on today's date? Or is the date inputted somewhere? (I cannot open the image from my work pc.)

Comment: Determine week number in VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46980531/478884  Then you can use `Application.Match()` for (eg) "Back", "44" and "Wk44" to locate the columns you need to work with.